# why we can't initiaize data member in a member function using list initializer?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

why assignment is working, but initialization not working ?
please explain what is happening in these 3 cases in code.

```
#include <iostream>

class Fun {
public:
    void set_data_variable()
    {
        y {2};      // case 1 : this doesn't work
        // y = 2;   // case 2 : this does work
        // y = {2}; // case 3:  this also work

        std::cout << y << "\n";
    }
private:
     int y = 6;
};

int main()
{
    Fun f;
    while (1) {
        f.set_data_variable();
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You can't initialize something that already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For intrinsic type (And also user defined classes) this syntax:

```
y {2};
```

Is only valid during object construction. The object `y` has already been constructed. It happened in the compiler generated function `Fun()` (The default constructor of the `Fun` class).

`y = 2;` and `y = {2};` work because they are assignment operations.

Comment: what does POD means ?

Comment: @user_xyz https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/what-are-pod-types-in-c